# ajax navigation error when using phonegap and ran locally

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

Sorry for the complete newbie question but i'm not having much luck.
I've created a project through eclipse with the phonegap plugin and deployed it as an android app onto a tablet to run locally - but I'm getting the 'Note: Navigation may not work if viewed locally' bar being added on the bottom of the pages.
How do I get round this? I thought if it was packaged up in this format I wouldn't have to install an android webserver onto the tablet and run it through the browser?
All guidance is much apreciated.

Comment: you dont need webserver on android, this is required only for the desktop browser due to security (which you can still omit by `--disable-web-security` browser switch) can you put more info like phonegap version, android version??

Comment: cardova1.8.1, android-sdk_r18-windows, i am using chrome how change the disable -web-security

Comment: on windows, right click on chrome shortcut, goto properties, in target text field append these `--allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security`

Comment: in mac, open chrome with this command in terminal, `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`

Comment: i am using chrome in windows xp , i couldnt append the --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security , i tried to add it with "C:\Documents and Settings\rew\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" but it says make sure that the path exists

Comment: make sure you put these switches outside of the quotes so it should be like this - `"C:\Documents and Settings\rew\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security`. If it is still not running then first make sure the chrome.exe path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the samme error, and it turned out that jquery.mobile was included twice. Removal of the twin reference resulted in removal of the Note.