# navigation may not work error in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I am newbie to phonegap development. I have developed an apk file for android in phonegap when i test the apk file in emulator it is giving me the below error message at the end of the page

```
Note: Navigation may not work if viewed locally

The Ajax-based navigation used throughout the jQuery Mobile docs may need to be viewed on a web server to work in certain browsers. If you see an error message when you click a link, please try a different browser.
```

I know the root cause for this is phonegap accesses the files loacally using `file:///`

I have searched through google and tried the solution but no solution

Can anyone please please help me on this, I am struggling with this

**Edit:**

here is my script to enable navigation

```
<script>
$( document ).on( "deviceready", function() {
    // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
alert("test")
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer not sure whether it is correct or wrong but the message was disappeared and functionality is working fine for me.

**js/index.js**

**comment this line in `index.js` file**

```
 $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {
    $( event.target ).append( message );   #you need to comment this line
   });
```

Comment: In order to fix it in my setup using Cordova & JQMobile 1.3.2 - I had to change it in...   

  
**. . . docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js**  
  
And, for JQMobile 1.4.5, you may have to change it here...  
  
**. . . demos/_assets/js/jqm-demos.js**.   I am pretty sure this will work for PhoneGap and Cordova.

Comment: Also, to add some more info to my comment above - I am publishing to both iOS and Android as stand-alone mobile apps using Cordova CLI.

Answer (score -1):

As say [dhaval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256447/ajax-navigation-error-when-using-phonegap-and-ran-locally#comment14842731_11256447)  in the comments of another question:

This error message is only for Desktop browsers, nothing happeng on mobile.

The best approach for a correct development environment is work with some local server like [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

You can test locally your project in the browser with something like: "localhost/yourproject"

Comment: Not sure why it was said that THIS ERROR MESSAGE IS ONLY FOR DESKTOP.... because I get it on mobile devices, in addition to desktop.